# 8/9 and 32/9 aspect ratio HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I make a html page with the following tech specifications?

- Vertical view aspect ratio: 8/9
- Horizontal view aspect ratio: 32/9

Comment: You know that an HTML page is not supposed to be fixed size, right?  It's supposed to flexibly fill whatever container it is poured in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aspect ratio is an attribute of the device screen/browser window, not the HTML-page itself. You can only configure styles based on the current aspect ratio by [aspect-ratio media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio)